# Simplify Haskell Type Signatures

Tags: haskell, types

My question is about how to work with Haskell type signatures analytically. To make it concrete, I'm looking at the "fix" function:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
```

and a little made-up function that I wrote to do Peano-ish addition:

```
add = \rec a b -> if a == 0 then b else rec (a-1) (b+1)
```

When I examine the types, I get my expected type for `fix add`:

```
fix add :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

And it seems to work like I'd expect:

```
> (fix add) 1 1
2
```

How can I work with the type signatures for `fix` and for `add` to show that `fix add` has the above signature? What are the "algebraic", if that's even the right word, rules for working with type signatures? How could I "show my work"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ghci` tells us

`add :: Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a`

modulo some typeclass noise since the second argument to `add` requires an `Eq` instance (you're checking it for equality with `0`)

When we apply `fix` to `add`, the signature for `fix` becomes

`fix :: ((a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a)) -> (a -> a -> a)`

Remember, the `a`s in `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` can have **any** type. In this case they have type `(a -> a -> a)`

Thus `fix add :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, which is exactly the right type to add two `a`s.

You can work with Haskell's type signatures in a very algebraic fashion, variable substitution works just like you'd expect. In fact, theres a direct [translation](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/) between types and algebra.

Comment: Thanks! I had worked out as much (that the `a` in `fix` must be `(a -> a -> a)`). But isn't a step still missing? Is there some intermediate between `((a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a)) -> (a -> a -> a)` and `a -> a -> a`?

Comment: Yes, you're partially applying `fix` to `add`. The resulting partially applied function has type `a -> a -> a`

Comment: @twopoint718 Applying `fix` to `add` removes the `((a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a))` argument from `fix`'s type.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez thanks, I think that did it. I see now how it works. Thanks all around.